# Assign ids to distinct groups based on desc column values

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using mysql 5.5. I want to assign unique id's to groups based on a column values.
Let's say I have a table `mytable`:

```
version_col   value_col
  vrsn1           100
  vrsn2           500
  vrsn2           300
  vrsn1           400
  vrsn3           100
```

I want to assign id's based on `version_col` column and for desc order for that column. Meaning latest vrsn value in `version_col` gets 0 as the id. 
Something like this:

```
version_col   value_col   id
  vrsn1           100     2    
  vrsn2           500     1
  vrsn2           300     1
  vrsn1           400     2
  vrsn3           100     0
```

I want to update the entire id column whenever I insert new records.

I'm a Python programmer, and I know this can be done using the Pandas package using `DataFrame.groupby.ngroup()` function. But I want to update the column using SQL query.

Any help in this would be much appreciated.

Comment: How do you know the "age" of a version?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Below method would sort your `version_col` and assign a row/group_id.

```
Select 
    T.version_col,
    IF(@o = T.version_col, @i, @i := @i+1) as group_id, -- Increase the group_id by +1 if the old version_col <> new version_col
    @o := T.version_col                                 -- [re]-initialise or take note of version_col
FROM
    myTable T join (select @i := -1) I                  -- here initialise your counter
ORDER BY 
    T.version_col desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `dense_rank()` function in MySQL 8+:

```
select t.*, dense_rank() over (order by version_col desc) - 1 as seqnum
from t;
```

However, this is unnecessary if you just want to get the most recent version in the table.  You can use:

```
select t.*
from t
order by t.version_col desc
limit 1;
```